# How to not get repeated names(Column A) appear in combobox and populate Column B names in new combo box

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I encountered a problem where I am not able to populate the Column A names in the "Combo Box 1" **without duplicates**. After removing diuplicates I need to populate the respective Column B values into "Combo Box2" by grouping Column A values. Is there anything in my codes that causes this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below Image of my Excel data:

[image]

**Output:** When select "A" from "Combo Box1" (without repeting A value 3 times) then it should populate "12,2,3" in "Combo box 2"

Below is the code to link the names to the combo Box.

```
Private Sub cboproj_DropButtonClick()
Dim ssheet As Worksheet
Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ssheet.Activate
Dim i As Long
If Me.cboproj.ListCount = 0 Then
    For i = 2 To ssheet.Range("A" & ssheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.cboproj.AddItem Sheets("LS numbers").Cells(i, "A").Value
        'remove duplicates
        ssheet.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    Next i
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboproj_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate
For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.cboproj) Or ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.cboproj) Then
        Me.cbonumber = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value  
        Me.cboloc = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value 
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: *not get repeated names(Column A)appear in combobox*: Use a Dictionary to get unique values before populating. *populate Column B names* Use a normal array, concatenating `Part` and `Nr`. Loop trough it and populate the combobox2 for each item in array that starts (Use `Left()`) with the string selected in Combobox1

Comment: I would do this slightly different. **1.** Store Excel Col A-B in an array.  **2.** Create a unique collection of values of Col A **3.** In Combobox A click event, match Combobox A value with the data in array and then populate Combobox B (Clear Combobox B first)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout your approach will workout but I am not understanding how to edit the Code to collect and store, can you please edit the Code lines

Comment: I am guessing you have a 3rd combo for loc? so when value from comboB is selected, you want to populate combo C?

Comment: Yes.. what you said is exactly i needed!!

Comment: ok gimme 15 mins

Comment: BTW, can there be duplicates in Col B and Col C?

Comment: only in Col C there can be duplicates but not in Col B

Comment: Posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, right click on all your 3 comboboxes and change their `Style` from `fmStyleDropDownCombo` to `fmStyleDropDownList`. This will ensure that the user cannot type something which is not there in the list.

**Logic**:

1. In the `UserForm_Initialize`, Sort the data in the excel sheet. This way the data will be sorted when it is added in the comboboxes.
2. Store Excel Col A-B in an array.
3. Create a unique collection of values of Col A. Add the items from the collection to Combobox1.
4. In Combobox A click event, match Combobox A value with the data in col 1 of array and then populate Combobox B (Clear Combobox B first)
5. In Combobox B click event, match Combobox B value with the data in col 2 of array and then populate Combobox C (Clear Combobox C first)

**My Assumptions**

1. The data is stored in a worksheet with a codename as `Sheet1`
2. `Part` has to go in `Combobox1`
3. `Nr.` has to go in `Combobox2`
4. `Loc` has to go in `Combobox3`

So make those changes in the code when you are implementing the below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyAr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim col As Collection
Dim itm As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set col = New Collection

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Sort Col A,B and C so that you get sorted data inthe combobox
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear

            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & lRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & lRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lRow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        '~~> Store the range in an array
        MyAr = .Range("A2:C" & lRow).Value

        '~~> Loop through Col A of the array and
        '~~> Create a unique collection
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            On Error Resume Next
            If Len(Trim(MyAr(i, 1))) <> 0 Then
                col.Add MyAr(i, 1), CStr(MyAr(i, 1))
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Add items to Combobox 1
    If col.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each itm In col
            ComboBox1.AddItem itm
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Clear for input
    ComboBox2.Clear
    ComboBox3.Clear

    '~~> Compare array and fill combobox 2
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If MyAr(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Value Then
           ComboBox2.AddItem MyAr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Click()
    If ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    ComboBox3.Clear

    Set col = New Collection

    '~~> Compare array and create a unique collection
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If Trim(MyAr(i, 1)) = (ComboBox1.Value) And _
           Trim(MyAr(i, 2)) = (ComboBox2.Value) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add MyAr(i, 3), CStr(MyAr(i, 3))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Fill combobox 3
    If col.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each itm In col
            ComboBox3.AddItem itm
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Super!!!! This works so perfect and Output is exactly as per my requirement.     Thanks alot :-)

Comment: Is it possible to replace a Combox3 to TextBox3 ? Do I need to Change the Code ?

Comment: Yes it is. For that in the `ComboBox2_Click()` code, you have to set the values as `textBox3.text = MyAr(i, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Option Explicit

Dim arr As Variant, value As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    value = Me.ComboBox1.value

    Me.ComboBox2.Clear

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        If arr(i, 1) = value Then
            dict.Add Key:=arr(i, 2), Item:=i
        End If

    Next i

    For Each value In dict
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem value
    Next value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        arr = .Range("A2:B" & LastRow)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add Key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=i
            End If
        Next i

        For Each value In dict
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem value
        Next value

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Siddharth Rout could you please evaluate?